# How do Android games and other engine-based complex apps retain state through - or otherwise handle - process death?

Tags: android, process, state, game-engine, retain

In particular I'm curious if game engines can survive process death, perhaps they are running as a separate process that isn't killed?
Or do they just restart the app so that they don't have to save all of the state?
Or do they generally save and reload all the stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save and reload.  Running as another process wouldn't help, there's no such thing as a process that can't be killed.  How/where they save is app dependent.